# XNA - Link between Create Rotations matrices

Tags: xna, c#, matrix

A friend of mine have been coding some rotations on my XNA project, but the order of the matrices rotation are not good. Some are of form :

```
Matrix.CreateRotationZ(1.21f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(-0.13f)
```

and other:

```
Matrix.CreateRotationY(1.01f) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(-0.5f) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(0.80f)
```

How can I find the values X, Y, Z so the rotations are in the correct order: (X,Y,Z) ?

```
Matrix.CreateRotationX(X) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(Y) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Z)
```

Comment: You listed Z-Y, then X-Y-Z.  Is the problem using axis rotations which might vary in their order of application?  If so, you should describe what determines their order.

Comment: For Z-Y, it assumes X = 1 (CreateRotationX(0))
But yes my problem is the order for application, CreateRotX*CreateRotY is not equal to CreateRotY*CreateRotX. So I just need to convert the values so I get the good order X*Y*Z.

Comment: @ApocKalipsS, are the current rotations correct? Do You need just to convert the rotations from the actual coordinate frame to the another new one?

Comment: The rotations are all correct, but the multiplication is not in the  order I want it to be..